# How to create multiple columns based on some conditions in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
Given Dataset:             New dataset:
ball  score                ball  score  current_score  total_score
 0.1      0                 0.1      0              0           13
 0.2      1                 0.2      1              1           13
 0.3      4                 0.3      4              5           13           
 1.1      0                 1.1      0              5           13
 1.2      2                 1.2      2              7           13
 2.1      6                 2.1      6             13           13
 0.1      1                 0.1      1              1            5
 1.1      3                 1.1      3              4            5
 1.2      1                 1.2      1              5            5
 0.1      6                 0.1      6              6            7
 0.2      0                 0.2      0              6            7
 0.3      1                 0.3      1              7            7
```

I want to create 2 columns whereas current_score = current_score + score until ball = 0.1 and for total_score it returns the max of current_score until ball = 0.1 (recursively)
My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("score.csv")
df['total_score'] = df.groupby(df['ball'].ne(df['ball'].shift())\
             .cumsum())['score'].transform('sum')
```

I am new in pandas. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first group by the 0.1's sequences found with `cumsum`, then `current_score` is the cumulative sum of the groups. For `total_score`, we `transform` the `current_score` with `max` with same groups:

```
gr = df.groupby(df.ball.eq(0.1).cumsum())
df["current_score"] = gr.score.cumsum()
df["total_score"] = gr.current_score.transform("max")
```

to get

```
>>> df

    ball  score  current_score  total_score
0    0.1      0              0           13
1    0.2      1              1           13
2    0.3      4              5           13
3    1.1      0              5           13
4    1.2      2              7           13
5    2.1      6             13           13
6    0.1      1              1            5
7    1.1      3              4            5
8    1.2      1              5            5
9    0.1      6              6            7
10   0.2      0              6            7
11   0.3      1              7            7
```